# Why build a Stone House if hitpoints are the same of a Log House?

Tags: medieval-engineers

Stone building parts are very resource-intensive, but have 800 hitpoints, just the same as Logs building parts.

Why take the extra efforts to gather the Stone materials? What is the advantage?

Comment: aesthetics.....

Comment: @alexanderpas Unlogic for a game developer to make me mine copper, to smelt, to build pickaxes, to gather stone, to build... When I could just chop some trees using a stone axe and build log cabins.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah why do people live in fancy expensive houses when they could live in shacks?

Comment: @Esther Because they don't have the trouble to mine the materials and build the house themselves?

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah they just have to work for many hours at a real job to earn the money for it. If it's not fun for you, don't do it. But for some people building a prettier house is fun, and that's who it's for.

Comment: @Esther Feudal lords don't have to work many hours to earn money, do they? Where are all my peasants? They should be breaking rocks for me.

Comment: Reported on their Bugtracker: https://communityedition.medievalengineers.com/mantis/view.php?id=401